# Изменение functions.php и styles.css в темах WordPress

Tags: wordpress, функции

Задача такая. На главной странице блога wordpress сделать так что бы превью постов были активными видеозаписями как здесь: thehaze.ru
В блоге у меня стоит тема и как я понял необходимо добавить к ней внутрь код вот этого плагина https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-video-plus/
потому что на автомате тема плагин не пускает.есть мнения на этот счет?

Comment: А что значит "на автомате не пускает"? Это как?

Comment: Я мозг сломал, пытаясь соотнести заголовок с телом вопроса.. Ида вопрос не ясен.

Comment: Я тут нашел свою старую шапку-телепатку и она нашептала, что нужно в анонсах вывести видео, вставленное шорткодом в пост. Шапка не сломалась?  Тогда показывай тему.

Comment: @SeVlad ТС хочет воткнуть код плагина в тему зачем-то. А в плагине этом штук 20 файлов php, css и js.

Comment: @KAGGDesign это он пока ДУМАЕТ, что это ему надо. Но может быть всё не так.

Answer (score 0):

1. Устанавливаете плагин, который вы описали.
2. На главной странице выводите список постов, который необходим (либо стандартными средствами, либо с помощью плагинов темы - все
   зависит от нее).
3. На странице редактирования поста добавляете ссылку на видео, которое хотите выводить в спец. блоке, который появляется после
   установки плагина.

И да, плагин не забудьте активировать.
И да, непонятен заголовок вашего вопроса :)